# How do Image Click Event works on Xamarin Forms - iOS Apps?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am relatively new to Xamarin Forms : iOS Apps. Just like any other Apps, I have to create an event on an Image. Home , Back , Account setting.

Whether these events are fired on Image Button Event ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no click event for the image. You have to create a Tap Gesture Recognizer for the image.

**Xaml:**

```
<Image Source="imageName.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnImageNameTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Xaml.cs:**

```
void OnImageNameTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
         {
            //Code to execute on tapped event
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
           throw ex;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Working Perfectly!